# Laravel: desplegables de campos relacionados

Tags: laravel, eloquent

La aplicación que estoy desarrollando, entre otras cosas, consta de un listado inicial de servicios. Cada servicio se realiza en una determinada población, que se corresponde con un municipio.

Cuando se hace clic en un servicio determinado se muestra la ficha de ese servicio.

En la ficha, entre otros, debería de mostrarse la población donde se ha realizado el servicio y el municipio al que corresponde dicha población.

En el desplegable de poblaciones deberían de aparecer sólo las poblaciones correspondientes al municipio de la población.
Y en el desplegable de municipios deberían aparecer todos los municipios y seleccionado el municipio correspondiente a la población del servicio.

*Los campos que intervienen son:*
de la tabla servicios: **idPoblacion**
de la tabla poblaciones: **id**, **idMunicipio**
de la tabla municipios: **id**, **nombre**

*Las relaciones son:*
servicios.idPoblacion -> poblaciones.id
poblaciones.idMunicipio -> municipios.id

*Las relaciones en laravel:*
En modelo **TServicio**:

```
public function a_poblacion(){
   return $this->belongsTo(APoblacion::class, 'idPoblacion');
}
```

En modelo **APoblacion**:

```
public function a_municipio(){
   return $this->belongsTo(AMunicipio::class, 'idMunicipio');
}

public function t_servicio(){
   return $this->hasMany(TServicio::class, 'idPoblacion');
}
```

En modelo **AMunicipio**:

```
public function a_poblacion()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(APoblacion::class, 'idMunicipio');
    }
```

El método, en **ServicioController.php**:

```
public function ficha($id)
    {
        $servicios = TServicio::where('id',$id)                          
                              ->with('a_poblacion')
                              ->with('a_municipio')->first();

        $poblacions = APoblacio::all();
        $municipis = AMunicipi::all();

        return view('servicios.servicios-ficha')->with('servicios',$servicios)
                                                ->with('poblaciones',$poblaciones)
                                                ->with('municipios',$municipios);
```

En el blade (HTML):

```
<select id="municipio" name="municipio">
   @empty($servicios->municipio)
      <option selected value="">seleccionar un municipio</option>
   @endempty
   @foreach ($municipios as $municipio)
      @if ($servicios->idMunicipio == $municipio->id)
         <option value="{{ $municipio->id }}" selected>{{ $municipio->nombre }}</option>
      @else
         <option value="{{ $municipio->id }}" >{{ $municipio->nombre }}</option>
      @endif
   @endforeach
</select>

<select id="poblacion" name="poblacion">
   @empty($servicios->poblacion)
      <option selected value="">seleccionar una población</option>
   @endempty
   @foreach ($poblaciones as $poblacion)
      @if ($servicios->idPoblacion == $poblacion->id)
         <option value="{{ $poblacion->id }}" selected>{{ $poblacion->nombre }}</option>
      @else
         <option value="{{ $poblacion->id }}" >{{ $poblacion->nombre }}</option>
      @endif
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Necesito saber cómo sacar el municipio correspondiente a la población guardada en la tabla servicios.
Y que, en el campo poblaciones del formulario, solo se muestren las poblaciones correspondientes al municipio donde se realizó el servicio.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creería que con la siguiente consulta deberías conseguir el resultado esperado:

```
TServicio::with('a_poblacion.a_municipio')->findOrFail($id);
```

Lo anterior debido a que:

- No puedes pasar en formato de array las relaciones debido a que en el modelo `TServicio` no existe ninguna relación llamada `a_municipio`
- La relación con el municipio está dada entre el modelo `AMunicipio` y `APoblacion` por lo tanto al no ser una relación directa, podemos acceder a ella a través de este último como una [relación anidada](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)
- **Opcionalmente** en lugar de filtrar con el método actual, usa mejor el método [`findOrFail`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) para retornar una excepción si el modelo no se encuentra.

Lo anterior te debería permitir recuperar:

- Datos del servicio realizado
- Datos de la(s) población(es) asociada(s) a ese servicio
- Datos del municipio vinculado al punto anterior

Comment: Desde el controlador hazle un dd a tu consulta para que revises en la salida si obtienes los datos esperados

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Con el `with->()` que me has puesto he ido probando distintas maneras de conseguir el id del municipio y al final he conseguido que funcione poniendo en el **controlador**, esto:

```
$servicios = TServicio::where('id',$id)                          
                      ->with('a_poblacion')
                      ->with('a_poblacion.a_municipio')->first();

$poblaciones = APoblacion::where('idMunicipio',$servicios->a_poblacion->a_municipio->id)->get();
$municipis = AMunicipi::all();
```

Y en la **vista**, esto otro:

```
<select id="municipio" name="municipio">
   @empty($servicios->municipio)
      <option selected value="">Selecciona municipio</option>
   @endempty
   @foreach ($municipios as $municipio)
      @if ($servicios->a_poblacion->a_municipio->id == $municipio->id)
         <option value="{{ $municipio->id }}" selected>{{ $municipio->nombre  }}</option>
      @else
         <option value="{{ $municipio->id }}" >{{ $municipio->nombre }}</option>
      @endif
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Gracias por la sugerencia de `findOrFail()`, pero los datos se validan antes de ser grabados.

Saludos.